# Where is $? saved in bash?

Tags: c, bash

I am trying to make a shell in C language and i need to add $?, so like in bash return the last command exit_status.
I have seen that it does not save $? in the ENV variables so my questions here are:

- How do I save it in order to match bash execution
- Should I assign a local variable to `perror`, in order to return the value when user types $?
- Why does $? return 127 on Linux and 1 on Mac on error

Thanks for reading or answering!

Comment: @haccks it is both C and Bash

Comment: The shell is just a program. It has its own memory and it can always access the filesystem. It can store/cache the value of the exit status of the last run program in either of those two.

Comment: That last one is a separate question.

Comment: Since it was related to $? top question about the return on the exit status i though of not making a new question, but yeah it could prob be in a different question

Comment: So you just need the last exit status to use it in your code? As a variable, lets say?

Comment: `man 1 exit` if available should tell  you why `127` and not `1` if that matters, not to mention there is a section called `EXIT STATUS` in the `man bash`

Comment: @Jetchisel that was actually a really good answer, still dont get why in Mac the return is different, but now i know more or less how to solve it, thanks!